# Onnx load error: The input tensor cannot be reshaped to the requested shape

Tags: tensorflow, onnx

I want to convert a tensorflow model to an onnx file, the conversion is successful and the file is saved. But when I load the onnx model with onnxruntime, it threw an error:

> onnxruntime.capi.onnxruntime_pybind11_state.RuntimeException: [ONNXRuntimeError] : 6 : RUNTIME_EXCEPTION : Non-zero status code returned while running Loop node. Name:'generic_loop_Loop__518' Status Message: Non-zero status code returned while running Reshape node. Name:'NmtModel/while/Reshape_1' Status Message: /onnxruntime_src/onnxruntime/core/providers/cpu/tensor/reshape_helper.h:37 onnxruntime::ReshapeHelper::ReshapeHelper(const onnxruntime::TensorShape&, std::vector&) size != 0 && (input_shape.Size() % size) == 0 was false. The input tensor cannot be reshaped to the requested shape. Input shape:{1,4,0,512}, requested shape:{1,-1,0,512}

Seems the `reshape` operation cannot accept the actual tensor shape of {1,4,0,512}, how can I solve this please?